# How do I resolve ambiguous mapping error when using spring oath provider?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to add Spring OAuth2 security to my application to secure my REST endpoints, which are Spring RestControllers. For the moment I'm just trying to get the basic pieces in place. However, something with the OAuth2 provider is generating an ambiguous mapping of oauth2AuthorizationEndpoint bean method.

I am using spring-security-web:3.2.8.RELEASE And pring-security-oauth2:2.0.7.RELEASE
 At startup I am getting the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'oauth2HandlerMapping': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping found. Cannot map 'authorizationEndpoint' bean method 
public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.AuthorizationEndpoint.authorize(java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>,org.springframework.web.bind.support.SessionStatus,java.security.Principal)
to {[/oauth/authorize],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}: There is already 'oauth2AuthorizationEndpoint' bean method
```

My configuration is:

```
<security:http pattern="/api/**" entry-point-ref="oauth2EntryPoint"
               access-decision-manager-ref="affirmativeBasedDecisionManager">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/api/mobile/survey/**" access="ROLE_CANVASSER"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/api/mobile/monitor/**" access="ROLE_MONITOR"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/api/**" access="ROLE_GEM_USER"/>
    <security:custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER"/>
    <security:access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"/>
</security:http>
```

```
<oauth:authorization-server
        client-details-service-ref="gemUserClientDetailsService" token-services-ref="tokenServices">
    <oauth:authorization-code />
    <oauth:implicit/>
    <oauth:refresh-token/>
    <oauth:client-credentials />
    <oauth:password authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager"/>
</oauth:authorization-server>

<bean id="defaultOAuth2UserApprovalHandler"       class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.DefaultUserApprovalHandler"/>

<bean id="tokenServices" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices">
    <property name="accessTokenValiditySeconds" value="86400"/>
    <property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore"/>
    <property name="supportRefreshToken" value="true"/>
    <property name="clientDetailsService" ref="gemUserClientDetailsService"/>
</bean>

<bean id="tokenStore" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.InMemoryTokenStore"/>
<bean name="gemDetailsService" class="com.factgem.gem.security.AuthenticationProvider"/>

<bean id="oauth2EntryPoint"   class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="realmName" value="gem"/>
</bean>

<bean id="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"        class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler"/>


<bean id="roleVoterHierarchyVoter" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleHierarchyVoter">
    <constructor-arg ref="roleHierarchy"/>
    <property name="rolePrefix" value="ROLE"/>
</bean>

<bean id="webExpressionVoter" class="org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter"/>

<bean id="webSecurityExpressionHandler"
      class="org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler">
    <property name="roleHierarchy" ref="roleHierarchy"/>
</bean>

<bean id="webExpressionHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter">
    <property name="expressionHandler">
        <ref bean="webSecurityExpressionHandler"/>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="authenticatedVoter" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter"/>

<bean id="jsr250Voter" class="org.springframework.security.access.annotation.Jsr250Voter"/>


<bean id="affirmativeBasedDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <ref local="roleVoterHierarchyVoter"/>
            <ref local="webExpressionVoter"/>
            <ref local="authenticatedVoter"/>
            <ref local="jsr250Voter"/>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Comment: Do you have multiple component scans for the same package somewhere in your configuration?

Comment: No. Just this one scan:
`<context:component-scan base-package="com.factgem"/>`

Comment: Where is your affirmativeBasedDecisionManager bean configured?

Comment: affirmativeBasedDecisionManager configuration added to original post

Comment: I can't tell without more info, but in webapps double bean definitions are often caused by both the root application context (initialized by the context listener) and the child application context (created by the dispatcher servlet) loading the same bean definitions. Same XML's included twice, or overlapping component scanning.